# Is their something like iframe in C#?

Tags: c#

Is their something like iframe in c#?

I want to build an application with one form that its content changes according to the actions I do, like messenger live. The part when I log in and log out its too different "windows" but it happens in the same form.

Answer (score 4):

There is no iframe equivalent in winforms or wpf, but there are ways to deal with it.

For either winforms or wpf, what you want to do is have a Panel which you change the content of.

A panel is a container which holds/encapsulates other controls.

If you have two different views you want to toggle between, create two panels at the same position with the content you need. Then you will show one and hide the other. When the user executes some action which requires you to change the view, then simply hide the displaying panel, and unhide/show the other one.

Think of it as layers, where you will only show one at a time.

You can also dynamically load user controls into a panel, much like an iframe, but I find it easier to have the content in the form, and hide/show as needed.

Comment: I think you mean, *No, there is no iframe in C#*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `WinForms`, how about using [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)? Place as many as you want in a single/multiple forms, and interact as you do in forms. See, [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a form into a Panel or tabPage from a TabControl:

```
Form f = new Form();
f.TopLevel = false;
panel1.Controls.Add(f);
f.Show();
f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```